# orientdb clusterselection, how can I distribute my records in each node averagely

Tags: orientdb

Orientdb verson 2.1.11.

I have 3 node, I want to distribute my records in each node averagely,my code is:

```
ODatabase database = new DatabaseDocumentTx("remote:node1;node2;node3/mydb").open("root", "1234");

System.out.println("selection:" + database.get(ODatabase.ATTRIBUTES.CLUSTERSELECTION));

database.command(new OCommandSQL("alter class Person clusterSelection round-robin"));

System.out.println("selection:" + database.get(ODatabase.ATTRIBUTES.CLUSTERSELECTION));

for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    ODocument document = new ODocument("Person");
    document.field("name", "pengtao.geng" + i);
    document.field("age", 28 + i);

    document.save();
    System.out.println("save " + i);
}
database.close();
```

however, it does't work. I try to modify class clusterselection by studio, it does't work too.

How can I do this,could you give me an example, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v2.2 OrientDB supports Load Balancing: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Distributed-Configuration.html#load-balancing. You can use `ROUND_ROBIN_REQUEST` strategy with this code (the servers must be in cluster):

```
ODatabase database = new DatabaseDocumentTx("remote:node1;node2;node3/mydb").open("root", "1234");

db.setProperty(OStorageRemote.PARAM_CONNECTION_STRATEGY, OStorageRemote.CONNECTION_STRATEGY.ROUND_ROBIN_REQUEST);

for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    ODocument document = new ODocument("Person");
    document.field("name", "pengtao.geng" + i);
    document.field("age", 28 + i);

    document.save();
    System.out.println("save " + i);
}
database.close();
```